# Printers for UX designers

Tags: printer

I’m looking to buy a printer for my UX agency, which I would ideally like to have the following features:

1. Auto double sided printing
2. WiFi/Bluetooth connection
3. Ability to print high quality documents up to A3
4. A scanner
5. Great quality photo finishes for poster
6. Flyer/business card/poster printing for clients
7. Don’t need to print a lot of pages per minute

Any recommendations? I’ve read a few articles and initially thought that I wanted a laser printer but it seems as though inkjet is the way to go. There’s so much choice so thought I’d ask those who know

Comment: You said "Great quality photo finishes for poster." Are you looking for a large format glossy photo printer?

Comment: What do you mean by large format? Glossy photo on photo paper isn’t essential but could be useful!

Comment: Do you have a budget for this printer?

Comment: @Cfinley up to £500 but I had originally budgeted about £1400 given that I was looking at laser ones